# Algorithm to output the initials of a name

Tags: java

I have just started the java programming and at the moment I am doing the basic things. I came across a problem that I can't solve and didn't found any answers around so I thought you might give me a hand. I want to write a program to prompt the user to enter their full name (first name, second name and surname) and output their initials.

Assuming that the user always types three names and does not include any unnecessary spaces. So the input data will always look like this : Name Middlename Surname

Some of my code that I have done and stuck in there as I get number of the letter that is in the code instead of letter itself.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Initials
{
     public static void main (String[] args)
     {
        //create Scanner to read in data
        Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 


        //prompt user for input – use print to leave cursor on line
        System.out.print("Please enter Your full Name , Middle name And Surname: ");
        String name = myKeyboard.nextLine();

                String initials1 = name.substring(0, 1); 
                int initials2 = name.

                //output Initials
                System.out.println ("Initials Are " + initials1 + initials2 + initials3);


     }
}
```

Comment: you're missing some code after `int initials2 = name.`, please repair

Comment: This is a Q&A site, **not** a forum. Set a more appropriate title.

Comment: if this is homework please mark it as such

Answer (score 3):

Users will enter a string like

"first middle last"

so therefore you need to get *each* word from the string.

Loot at [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

After you get each word of the user-entered data, you need to use a [loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to get the first letter of each part of the name.

Answer (score 2):

First, the nextLine Function will return the full name.  First, you need to `.split()` the string `name` on a space, perhaps.  This requires a correctly formatted string from the user, but I wouldn't worry about that yet.

Once you split the string, it returns an array of strings.  If the user put them in correectly, you can do a for loop on the array.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(3);
for(int i = 0; i < splitStringArray.length; i++)
{
    builder.append(splitStringArray[i].substring(0,1));
}

System.out.println("Initials Are " + builder.toString());
```

Comment: you should really want to 'teach him to fish' instead of just 'giving him a fish'.

Comment: @hvgotcodes In some cases, I will agree, but he also said he's doing very basic things as well.  If he is really interested in learning, he can choose to learn what the code says, which will teach him more through reasoning in his own logic.

Comment: more likely he is just going to take that and submit it as part of a homework assignment

Comment: @hvgotcodes in my experience, those that do exactly that, don't end up doing well in a programming class in either case. If he really chooses that route, he's already digging a grave for his grade. I'd prefer to think that not all first timers here are just looking for homework help.

Comment: +1 I agree with David. We're not going to be there to help students on their tests, etc. So if they 'cheat' on their homework, they're just going to end up getting a bad grade in the class anyways. And I know a bunch of people from college that graduated with CS majors and can't get a job because they didn't really know the material. So if they use our answers and don't bother to understand them, they'll just kill themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Use the String `split()` method. This allows you to split a String using a certain regex (for example, spliting a String by the space character). The returned value is an array holding each of the split values. See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for the method.

```
Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

System.out.print("Please enter Your full Name , Middle name And Surname: ");
String name = myKeyboard.nextLine();

String[] nameParts = name.split(" ");

char firstInitial = nameParts[0].charAt(0);
char middleInitial = nameParts[1].charAt(0);
char lastInitial = nameParts[2].charAt(0);

System.out.println ("Initials Are " + firstInitial + middleInitial + lastInitial);
```

Note that the above assumes the user has entered the right number of names. You'll need to do some catching or checking if you need to safeguard against the users doing "weird" things.